# Close Multiplayer Connection within Single Scene

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer

I have these question regarding multi-player game that I have built. I have gone through multiplayer tutorial available in Unity website and watched few paid online multiplayer courses too. Still I am not clear about these questions so I asking here and hope someone will give proper details about this:

- In multiplayer game, how can I remove a player when he died from multiplayer network? Mostly all tutorials spawning him again so they are doing repositioning. I want to completely remove died player from game.
- In multiplayer game, when this device player died how to close multiplayer connection? Because I have not used separate scene for multiplayer activity within same scene I was running single player and multiplayer modes of game. So I want to close multiplayer connection properly, again game player can connect with new match. Following image represent my point:

[image]

I have these questions regarding current project implementation, I hope some one will explain this to me.

Comment: Which Unity Version / Multiplayer are you using? I don't really see how the attached screenshots would help to represent your point..

Comment: It looks like your `DodgetsNetworkManager` component inherits from `NetworkManager`? Did you try using [`NetworkManager.singleton.StopClient`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.4/Documentation/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkManager.StopClient.html)?

Comment: First thank you sir for your interest for helping me. Unity version I was using 2017.3.1p4 - Yes, DodgelsNetworkManager inherited from NetworkManager. At present I was using DodgelsNetworkManager.singleton.StopHost (); on both connected players. I have single scene through which game player can again and again create match and start game with remote players.

Comment: `StopHost` si ofcourse only allowed if you are the Host ;) Clients have to use `StopClient` so you have to check who you are and than deside which one to use ... but you should rather use a dedicated Server setup than because if the Host stops, than everyone is kicked out of the network

Comment: At present, I was working on 2 players small game so I require to close host too with one player defeat. - how can I check whether this device is host or client when I was on game over page? because I was destroying both players on my game over page based on game requirements to show players at game over too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [NetworkManager.singleton.StopClient](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.4/Documentation/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkManager.StopClient.html) on the client and [NetworkManager.singleton.StopHost](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.4/Documentation/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkManager.StopHost.html) on the host, [NetworkManager.singleton.StopMatchMaker](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.4/Documentation/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkManager.StopMatchMaker.html) depending on your needs.

You can find out who is who by using the [NetworkBehaviour](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.4/Documentation/Manual/class-NetworkBehaviour.html) properties `isClient` and `isServer` on the player GameObjects.

Since you said you want to also be able to check this if there is no player anymore you could somehow store it right after you connected e.g.

```c#
public enum ConnectionType
{
    Unknown,
    Client,
    Host
}

public static class WhoAmI
{
    public satic ConnectionType Type;
}
```

and than somewhere in a script on your player object e.g. in `Awake` do

```c#
WhoAmI.Connection = isServer ? ConnectionType.Host : ConnectionType.Client;
```

If you want to connect again later you than could use the opposide methods [NetworkManager.singleton.StartMatchMaker](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.4/Documentation/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkManager.StartMatchMaker.html) , [NetworkManager.singleton.StartHost](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.4/Documentation/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkManager.StartHost.html), [NetworkManager.singleton.StartClient](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.4/Documentation/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkManager.StartClient.html)

Comment: yes sir I got your above point...now within game, I was not reinitiating scene again to start new match and game. I stick with same loaded scene - I have multiplayer game prefab that I was instantiating again and again. After safely removed both players from game as per above reply. Now may I require to close match or room that I have created?? - Otherwise next time when player connected, it will find same match and joined in that which was garbage now.

Comment: Thank you sir for above reply - Definitely I will give a try to above answer and reply back to you quickly then after I will make this answer as correct to so other users can follow too.